Terraform Workspaces with GitHub Actions and GCP Backend: Handling multi-project auth
I have a Terraform config with a workspace for each environment (let's call the environments A, B, and C). Each environment has its own GCP project. Additionally, I use a separate GCP project (let's call this D) for managing my Terraform backend state.
Now comes the tricky part, I want to set up GitHub Actions to plan and apply my terraform config. However, even when considering a single environment, it's not clear to me how auth would work. Let's say I'm applying the config for environment A, the Terraform state still needs to be read from GCP project D.
This feels like it would be a common problem, but I haven't found any resources discussing it. Does anyone have insight into how I might approach this?
Thanks!

Check gcp service account option.

Create a service account for your backend, provide storage rights for that.
Authenticate the service account for your project env A

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account
-A
